# Flutter: Route from one tab to another tabs nested route programatically

Tags: flutter, routes, navigator

I have a BottomNavigationBar with 2 tabs.
Each of these tabs has its own Navigator inside.
On tab 2 I have a button.
When the button is clicked, I want to access a nested route of tab 1.

Bare minimum example:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedIndex,
        children: [
          Navigator(
            onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
              return MaterialPageRoute(
                  settings: settings,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    switch (settings.name) {
                      case '/':
                        return Container(color: Colors.blue);
                      case '/coffee2':
                        return Container(color: Colors.red);
                      default:
                        return Container(color: Colors.black);
                    }
                  });
            },
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/coffee2'),
            child: const SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              child: Text('Go to Coffee2'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

When clicking the GestureDetector, I get the following error:
`could not find a generator for route RouteSettings`

Comment: Take a look at this [sample](https://github.com/SchabanBo/qr_samples/blob/main/lib/common_cases/bottom_nav_bar.dart)

Comment: Isn't it possible to achieve this without an additional package?

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/your-route-name");
```

Comment: Results in the same error

Comment: Are you using two MaterialApp widgets?

Comment: No, its very basic and all just in one file with one MaterialApp widget on top.

Comment: Can you provide us with your full file (via github, google drive, etc.) so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: use Pastebin to get the code

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/flutter-template-forked-bk61u7?file=/lib/main.dart